# Test if prerender works locally?

Tags: html, prerender

I am using the following tag to prerender:

```
<link rel="prerender" href="//address.se/sv/get-started.html">
```

I am running the website locally at the moment. Is there any test I can run (perhaps via the chrome inspector) to see if my browser finds and prerenders the file?

Comment: First of all, `prerender` is a google chrome feature making things as usual (google makes all google wants), but the standard specification is `prefetch`. There's my suggestion, the problem you describe you can view it in the NETWORK tab of your developer tools.

Comment: See more: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#link-type-prefetch

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can test if prerender is happening locally, though it is little harder and requires tools beyond the regular developers tools.

Notice that at the time this question was asked, prerender was doing something different than what it does now, previously it used to prerender the whole page in a hidden renderer process, now it does something less powerful than that ([NoState Prefetch](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/nostate-prefetch))

### To check what has been pre-rendered:

- go to chrome://net-export/ ( this will export a log of all the network activities happening from all chrome windows, apps, and extensions)
- go to the website where you want to check prerendering, give it some time to idle and do the prerendering
- save the json file from the net export page, and load it into https://netlog-viewer.appspot.com/
- After its loaded, check the Prerender page found in the menu in the left side